# I just installed elementary OS and everything was working, but now display scaling is messed up

Tags: display, scaling

As mentioned everything was working fine, but then I tried mirror display and the scaling went bad. Now I can't access the setting to undo it because it's at the bottom of the window and won't fit in the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem setting **Scalling factor:** to **Pixel Doubled** and the only way I found to resolve this is by 'guessing' pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> again and again until i saw the sacalling factor select on the screen and I choose again LoDPI. If you have external monitor connected and you didn't messup with the system shortcuts, you can achieve this by <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> which is used to circle between known display modes.

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking off the top of my head here: Can you click on the title bar and move the window towards the lower right-hand corner just a bit? If you can, you should then be able to get a screen resize arrow. Then try re-sizing the window to where it's small enough and you move the window so you can access the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Hold ⌘ (super key) and click and drag on the window to move it. This way you can get to the bottom of the window.